# How to rename environment name in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have different environments like d1,q1,u1,p1. So when i run the below code in dev suppose then i get the output as d1

```
IHostEnvironment environment;
var envname = environment.EnvironmentName
```

I get it as d1 instead of dev as in azure it is called as d1. How do I rename it to dev?

Comment: You really should prefer the standard environment names `"Production"` and `"Development"` as a whole bunch of built-in functionality only recognizes those environment names. If you need machine-specific logic you should use a different and custom environment-variable entirely now - because the original intention of .NET Core's `EnvironmentName` (which was for this purposes) has been ruined by third-party (and first-party!) libraries and components that assume it's either `Production` or `Development` - it's annoying, I know.

Comment: @Dai so how do i do it with custom env variable?

Comment: you want your environment variable changed to "dev" from "d1" in azure instance right?

Comment: @FahimAbrar no not in azure instance. In azure instance it should be d1 itself but in .net core if it is d1 then i want to show it as dev

Comment: The environmental varaible list is a Window method and not core.  You are running on a different operating system so you are getting different names.  So you have two choice.  Make you code robust that check the operating system and depending on the type of operating system reads a differenrt name, or add to each user account an new environmental varaible.  The is an environmental variable OS which give the operating system.

Comment: @ashish can you edit your question elaborately? better with pictorial or illustration